# UIStackView can't set bottom constraint when using UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uistackview

I have UIView where a UIStackView is a subview.  Normally it fills the UIView.  However, when I embed the UIView in a UINavigationController the UIView and UIStackView no longer extend to the bottom of the screen.  It seems that they are getting a height that is only necessary to contain the UIStackView's subviews and nothing more. Here's what the constraints code looks like:

```
func setContraints() {

    readableContentGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    readableContentGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    readableContentGuide.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    readableContentGuide.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
    stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)

}
```

This line from above has no effect:

```
stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
```

And here is how I'm setting up the UINavigationController in AppDelegate:

```
window = UIWindow()
    let homeViewController = BeginCheckoutViewController()
    let navController  = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeViewController)
    self.window?.rootViewController = navController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: Where are you calling `setConstraints` from?

Answer (score 0):

We got a similar problem only on iPhoneX. Have you tried a different simulator? Maybe it's the same problem.

Try to use the bottomAnchor instead of safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor: `stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)`

On iPhoneX the safeAreLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor is not identical with the bottomAnchor because of the round edges (else there might be content missing). So if you do not have a UITabBar or something at bottom of your screen that fill the gap, this might help.

Comment: I tried a different simulator and also have been running on my iPhone 6s.  The behavior is the same when I try what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`stackView.setCustomSpacing(100, after: YourLastItemInStackview)`

OR

You can add an empty UIView as a last item of stack view with the height you expect for bottom margin.